# Moto E 1st Gen. network issue after Lollipop update

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, calls, sim-card, motorola-moto-e

After updating my Moto E 1st Gen. to Lollipop by OTA, my phone indicates that the mobile network is available, but any callers receive a message stating the phone has been switched off.

Calling any number from Moto E with any SIM will fix this issue. Restarting phone also solves issue, but I don't know **when it happens and why**.

Needs some suggestions to resolve this.

Comment: Have you tried to [Wipe cache partition](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IQc5ITk8ueI)?

Comment: I don't actually understand your second paragraph. When you call a number from your phone, does the call go through?

Answer (score -1):

Try to factory reset your phone after taking a backup. It is recommended that before any system update you should do a factory reset and wipe the cache partition. This should solve your problem.